# Get OS Win 7 username Javascript

Tags: javascript, api

Is it possible to get Windows username and PCName with Javascript in browsers IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera?

Comment: Purely with client-side JavaScript? I certainly hope not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Windows username with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968690/get-windows-username-with-javascript)

Comment: I can't believe there's even an earlier duplicate question.

Answer (score 6):

No. That sort of information is not exposed to the javascript engine in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

i'd really wish this wouldn't be possible, but sadly it is (or was). i don't know for sure if this still works on Win7 and with current browser-versions, but in the past you could do this...

**Internet Explorer**

```
function getUsr() {
   var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
   return wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%");
}
```

Comment: Yeah on W7 I'm getting Permission denied for <https://www.mysite.com> to get property XPCComponents.classes. Thankfully!