# Get windows user name using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**I tried to get the windows user name in IE browser only using the below code.**

```
function GetUserName() 
{ 
    var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); 
    alert(wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")); 
}
```

**How to get the windows username in other browsers like chrome, mozilla, safari.**

Comment: Uhm. I'm surprised you can do this in IE! This is incredibly intrusive and shouldn't be done. I'm pretty sure that _privacy conscious_ browsers like Chrome and Safari dont do that. They also dont support ActiveX. Thank god.

Answer (score 4):

I Agree with Eric comment. However try following hacks. Most likely to work in win7

**In IE**

```
var objUserInfo = new ActiveXObject("WScript.network");
document.write(objUserInfo.ComputerName+"<br>"); 
document.write(objUserInfo.UserDomain+"<br>"); 
document.write(objUserInfo.UserName+"<br>");  
var uname =  objUserInfo.UserName;
alert(uname);
```

**Firefox:**

```
function getUser() {
   return Components
     .classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"]
     .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment)
     .get('USERNAME');
}
```

**Source:** [Get OS Win 7 username Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802602/get-os-win-7-username-javascript)

[JavaScript - How to get the name of the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518092/javascript-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-user)

[Get Windows username with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968690/get-windows-username-with-javascript)

Comment: The javascript for firefox is not working properly.. And am looking mainly to get the user name for the following three browsers 

-IE 
-Firefox 
-Chrome

Is there any other way to find in all three browswers?

Comment: what about chrome?

Comment: The JavaScript you have posted for Firefox is only valid in a legacy extension. It isn't valid in a normal webpage. Including it here is inappropriate.

Answer (score 3):

As of today it is impossible, and will most likely be in the future as well.

The only quirk I can come up with; is to run a custom Java-Applet that checks it for you. However this is a passive action, and thus, you can not automatically extract it without the clients permission.

Comment: But, just to add, even using an applet shouldn't really be done. If you have to ask for user permission anyway, just ask the user to type in their name in a dialog or something. Otherwise this privacy disaster should be avoided.