# Why Components.classes is undefined?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

In Firefox when I am running the following code:

```js
var clazz = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger;1"];
```

This error is coming:

```
TypeError: Components.classes is undefined
```

Please see this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/BbrvX/

For information about `Components.classes` visit the following link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Components.classes

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 3):

`Components.classes` is for chrome code, extensions or browser development. You don't have access to it in content pages.

Comment: But, when I am running that code in developer tools opened in a new tab, the value is not undefined, instead it gives an object which can be used to get a service.

Comment: @user2856930: It's possible that when you are in a new tab with no content loaded yet, you are really in a chrome context. You are actually at the "about:newtab" url. If you run your code in the console for a page where you have non-xul content loaded, you should get an error. Note that there is also the "Enable chrome debugging" option that could play a role.

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing your addon using the [Addon SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) you should use this idiom:

```
var { Cc } = require("chrome");
var clazz = Cc["@mozilla.org/messenger;1"];
```

where Cc stands for Component.classes. You can read more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority).

Comment: Is there any way to use Components.classes without using Add-on SDK.

Comment: How do I get Components.Constructor?

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, new occurrence of the error:

If you used Component.Classes in a .cfg file, you will get this error in Firefox 64 bits.

For now, the workaround seems to be to add this line to the autoconfig.js file, to disable the sandbox in Firefox Quantum / 64 bits.

```
pref("general.config.sandbox_enabled", false);
```

This tip from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1236295 was suggested for Firefox 62, but also worked for me in Firefox 68.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23838138)

Comment: Updated with the actual fix

Comment: After adding this preference in about:config, I opened the debugger from this same tab and the "Cc" and "Ci" objects were defined. Opening from other tabs did not work.