# How to load Component and its Classes in my website

Tags: javascript

I am trying to over ride one the notification popups of browser using the following code:

```
var branch = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
```

**But in Mozilla Firefox, I get the error Component.classes is undefined.
And in Chrome Browser, I get the error Component is undefined.**

Well I have realised I need to include something in my website. But I am unable to find exactly what is required.

Please anybody help. I googled about it a lot, but I have never used this thing before(the Classes) and I am unable to search what will help me out. i dont even have any idea that what will be the tags for this thing. I have never used Component or its classes

My website is in ZF2.

Comment: Did you define `Components` in your JavaScript anywhere? In Google Chrome, that's not a built-in variable and I've never heard of it being a built-in variable from anywhere.

Comment: See if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378058/why-components-classes-is-undefined) helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Components` Object is non-standard feature. See  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Components_object.

It also says

> Warning: This object is only intended for code running with chrome
>   privileges. Exposing the object to regular web code was a mistake.