# Run exe from JavaScript code in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to execute a .exe file via javascript, but ActiveX in Mozilla is not supported.

I read that it could be done via `nslProcess`so I tried the following:

```
var exe = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    exe.initWithPath("c:\\WINDOWS\\notepad.exe");
    alert("exe");
    var run = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
    run.init(exe);
    var parameters = [""];
    run.run(false, parameters,parameters.length);
      alert("in function RunBat");

}
```

And got the following error:

```
TypeError: Components.classes is undefined.
```

What did I do wrong and are there any alternatives that are supported by the latest versions of Firefox?

P.S.
I have all full access on localhost.

**Update:**
Can I create Firefox extension which get value of inputExePath field in simple webpage and run exe in that path?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378058/why-components-classes-is-undefined

Comment: Thank god, this is not possible. The code you've tried would only work inside Firefox add-on.

Answer (score 0):

`Components.classes` is not accessible via JavaScript running in a webpage, it is only accessible via JavaScript running in a [Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension).