# PHP get windows Full Name

Tags: php, windows, account

Is it possible to get the windows user logged in account first name and last name without getting into the active directory?

Comment: i think you cant do that with only pure PHP

Comment: Unfortunatly you can't

Comment: that's not possible with PHP itself as PHP only workes on the Server itself  and can only use the date the user sends. THe name which he hase in windows is not included in that.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side programming language, you should be able to do that with a client-side programming language such as Javascript. I invite you to read the following topic on Programmers to clarify the situation: [What are the differences between server-side and client-side programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)

The question has been discussed in this topic: [Get Windows username with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968690/get-windows-username-with-javascript)

Comment: I was able to get the username of the logged user by using:


shell_exec("echo %username%" );

Comment: This way, you'll get the username of the server, not of the client.
If it is what's you're looking for, fine then, but this will not work on Linux servers.